# REgex to extract date and time

Tags: python, regex

I am using nltk regex for date and time extraction:

```
text = 'LEts have quick meeting on Wednesday at 9am'
week_day = "(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)"
month = "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september| \
          october|november|december)"
dmy = "(year|day|week|month)"
exp2 = "(this|next|last)"
regxp2 = "(" + exp2 + " (" + dmy + "|" + week_day + "|" + month + "))"
reg2 = re.compile(regxp2, re.IGNORECASE)
found = reg2.findall(text)
found = [a[0] for a in found if len(a) > 1]
for timex in found:
    timex_found.append(timex)

print timex_found
```

Everything looks right to me, but it does not tag `Wednesday` any clue? What change should I make to consider "wednesday" as well "this wednesday"

Will

```
regxp2 = "((this|next|last)? (" + dmy + "| " + week_day + "| " + month+ "))"
```

consider my case?

Comment: Go through it line by line and figure out if that line is producing the expected result. When you've done that, if you can't figure out how to fix it, you will have a [mcve] that is actually minimal.

Comment: There is no `(this|next|last)` in your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is looking for `((this|next|last) (dmy|weekday|month))`.

Your input doesn't have a match.

Some alternatives that may work:

```
((this|next|last|on) (dmy|weekday|month))

((this|next|last)? (dmy|weekday|month))
```

Comment: Thanks, but can we tag `This day` and `day` both if any of present

Comment: @user3449212 - second suggestion in the answer allows an optional `this|next|last`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am very poor with regex. can you please tell how to use it

Comment: `regxp2 = "((this|next|last)? (" + dmy + "| " + week_day + "| " + month+ "))"` is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, or `regxp2 = "(" + exp2 + "? (" + dmy + "|" + week_day + "|" + month + "))"`